# Faddeev Popov determinant for $U(1)$

Tags: path-integral, functional-determinants

The Faddeev-Popov determinant in case of $U(1)$ turns out to be ${\rm Det}(\partial^2)$.

My question is: what is the determinant of $\partial^2$?

Comment: Every text that introduces the notion of the FP determinant should also "compute" it e.g. by the standard procedure of expressing it as a fermionic Gaussian integral, thereby introducing ghost fields. What *exactly* is your question?

Comment: I thought by introducing the ghost fields we bypass the calculation of the determinant.

Answer (score 3):

It is a constant number. The $U(1)$ is indeed a quite trivial case.